# Is $f\sim g$ an appropriate notation for L' Hôspital Rule?

Tags: limits, notation

Let's say $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} f(x)=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} g(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1$.

Conventionally we write 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1$$

Can we use the asymptotically equal symbol ($\sim$) instead?
$$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\sim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\to1 \text{ as } x\to0$$

Comment: Asymptotically equal is usually used for *large values* of the variable so it would make sense for limits $x \to \infty$, but to my feeling not so much for $x \to 0$  (or any other finite $a$).

Comment: Are there "alternative notations" to the clumsy $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}$ to use L'Hopital Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are of course free to use whatever notation you want as long as you describe it in advance, and do not make it nonsensical (like "here $+$ will denote multiplication with 4").

Generally, $f(x) \sim g(x)$ denotes $f/g \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$, not $x \to 0$.

I have never seen anything other than what you are writing. $\lim_{x \to 0}$ is pretty standard and I don't find it particularly clumsy, it says exactly what it needs to and no more (like mathematical notation in general?). Remember that L'Hopital's rule is applicable not just for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Just my personal preference. When I draft calculations, I tend to miss out $\lim$ after $=$ and thus like to use $\to$ more.

Comment: @user2513881 Yeah, that happens to the best of us. :)